# How do I get the IP address of a switch

Tags: ip, switch, scripting

I have a wireless AP+switch which I configured years ago, before moving, and haven't used for a while. Now I want to reconfigure it for my new network, but have no idea what I set as its IP address(It was probably something 192.168.xx.yy). What is the best way for discovering its IP? A script to spam the whole address space?

Comment: Does it have a reset button so you can just switch it back to the factory defaults?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't remember the IP/subnet, you're likely not going to remember the security/authentication settings and passphrase either, so I'd just reset it to factory default.  There's likely a reset button on the back and some combination of power cycle/holding it down that you can find by googling the AP model for a manual.

Comment: +1 - nice observation.

Answer (score 2):

The [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) command can quickly ping any address range. For example,

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.0-254
```

Comment: nearly -1... not so fast if you dont remember the subnet ;)

Comment: nmap -sP 192.168.0-254.0-254

Answer (score 1):

By "spam", do you mean "scan"? If so, then yes that's one way to do it. You can use something like [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home) to scan your subnet for devices with ip addresses and then try them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply connect your PC to the AP/Switch with a direct cable and obtain the IP from your IP settings of this PC (Gateway)?

Comment: Switch has dhcp disabled.